# Using output of one sql query into another

Tags: sql, jdbc

I have 2 SQL queries in single line as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NameCode,Name FROM tblNames) AS X, (SELECT SUM(Mo+Tu) FROM tblFieldDays WHERE tblFieldDays.NameCode =36)
```

The first query i.e. (SELECT NameCode,Name FROM tblNames) gives a list of users.
Now I want to calculate sum of Mo+Tu i.e. SUM(Mo+Tu) for each user generated by first query.

i.e. I want to provide NameCode generated in first query instead of current 36 value which static just for example

I also tried to use IN statement as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NameCode,Name FROM tblNames) AS X, (SELECT SUM(Mo+Tu) FROM tblFieldDays WHERE tblFieldDays.NameCode IN (X.NameCode)) AS Y
```

But didnt work.
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Your `IN` syntax is bad.  I can't make sense of exactly what you're trying to do, but you need something like `Select SUM(the_value_field) FROM YOUR_TABLE where USER_ID in (SELECT ID FROM USER_TABLE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
SELECT NameCode, Name,
       (SELECT SUM(MO + TU)    
          FROM tblFieldDays Y
         WHERE Y.NameCode IN (X.NameCode))
  FROM tblNames X;
```

This statement selects all names and code from your table tblNames and adds the sum with a sub select.

Check out [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/958b0/3).

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: Awsome. Was trying this for long time. Saved me from writing different method for each request. Thanks ALOT

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  NameCode,
        Name,
        UserFieldDays = SUM(fieldDays.Mo + fieldDays.Tu)
  FROM  tblNames users
        JOIN tblFieldDays fieldDays ON users.NameCode = fieldDays.NameCode
GROUP BY users.NameCode, users.Name
```